# Different BIC value from strucchange plot and reconstructed model

Tags: r, bic, structural-change

I'm analysing a time series with the aim of assessing the presence of significant break points, using R package `strucchange` (v. 1.5-1).
The number of break points considered for interpretation should be based on the BIC.

```
bi <- data.frame( one=c(-291.646215, -352.906441, -203.847738, -265.890719, -239.569567, -115.730344,  -26.390263, -132.666324, -304.392077, -203.838021,-40.730929, -111.718441,
-134.439897, -256.708336, -100.273491,  -94.650407, -224.786040, -255.487975, -248.194932, -147.786471, -378.227251, -203.866693, -186.334344, -176.35081,7
-195.005512,  -96.399400, -151.217169, -215.296981, -132.246881, -410.438924, -305.406041, -438.224547, -334.886909, -304.906075, -249.427925, -277.21129,5
-391.637535, -506.200948, -410.195394, -249.840484, -353.658063, -294.074160, -306.975331, -196.784605, -224.970929,  -77.684773, -113.751598, -334.41126,6
-250.120219, -186.494178, -256.462787, -152.020462, -138.775345,  -84.182954,  -28.133517,  -53.180936, -241.289883,  -69.507575,  -16.108901,  -10.659180,
 -7.893134))

bits<-ts(bi$one,frequency=1)
bp<-breakpoints(bits~1,h=.15)

plot(bp,main="")
```

The resulting plot shows a BIC around ~739 for the 3-breakpoints model (black line, left scale).

[image: Left scale gives BIC]

However, when I then use `breakfactor` to reconstruct the model (for further plotting) :

```
bp3 <- breakpoints(bits~1,h=.15,breaks = 3)
fm3 <- lm(bits ~ breakfactor(bp3, breaks = 3))

BIC(fm3)
```

The resulting BIC is smaller (727).

Which value should I consider ? Why is there a difference ?

More precisely, I'd like to compare with the BIC from other models obtained previously with `lm` and `nls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in how the degrees of freedom (df) are calculated. This is most easily seen from extracting the `logLik()` which includes the `df`. Additionally, the `nobs()` can be consulted to check whether the number of observations is indeed the same (which is the case here).

```
logLik(fm3)
## 'log Lik.' -352.8972 (df=5)
nobs(fm3)
## [1] 61
```

The 5 parameters are intercepts in the 4 segments plus 1 constant variance. From these two pieces of information `BIC()` puts together the information criterion:

```
BIC(fm3)
## [1] 726.3488
-2 * (-352.8972) + log(61) * 5
## [1] 726.3488
```

The estimated breakpoints `bp3` or, equivalently, `bp` (because this is associated with the minimum-BIC solution) count the `df` differently and hence lead to a different BIC:

```
logLik(bp3)
## 'log Lik.' -352.8972 (df=8)
nobs(bp3)
## [1] 61
BIC(bp3)
## [1] 738.6814
-2 * (-352.8972) + log(61) * 8
## [1] 738.6814
```

The `df` are 8 and not 5 because `bp` and `bp3` account for the fact that in addition to the 5 parameters above 3 breakpoints were estimated. In contrast, `fm3` assumes that the segment specification is given exogenously.

Additionally, you could consider the variances to differ across the four segments. However, given that least-squares estimation is used (as opposed to full maximum likelihood estimation) we had decided to keep the standard homoscedastic view by default. See Zeileis, Shah, Patnaik (2010, *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, **54**(6), 1696-1706. [doi:10.1016/j.csda.2009.12.005](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2009.12.005)) for an approach that considers the variance a full model parameter.

Comment: The answer of @Achim Zeileis helped me a lot in a current problem, but I still wonder how to deal with the d.f. in case we compare two breakpoint models in a likelihood ratio test, e.g. `anova(fm3, fm0)`?

Comment: If you run `anova()` this assumes that the breakpoints were given exogenously and didn't need to be estimated. This then leads to a standard F test. However, when you want to account for estimation of the breakpoints (as appropriate here) you can use the same test statistic but it is no longer F-distributed. In `strucchange` we only implement the maximally-selected likelihood ratio test for 0 vs. (at least) 1 breakpoint, see `?Fstats`. In the literature you also find test for 0 vs. k or k vs. k+1 breaks. See the Bai & Perron (2003, Journal of Applied Econometrics) paper for more details.